# Role expire module in drupal 7

Tags: 7

[image]

When I assign custom role to any user here `impact protection user` then after its expiry date it automatically assigns role to authenticated user. How can I remove or disable that option to not automatically assigns to authenticated user. If specified date expires then user will unable to login for that specified role `impact perfection user`?

Answer (score 1):

Authenticate user being selected won't make a difference as the expiry date is on your other role of impact protection user.

Every user by default is an authenticated user, of which you can't make expire.

Comment: After expiry date user having assigned `impact protection user` can login as authenticated user. I want to restrict the user after its expiry date to not login again

Comment: For the role of authenticated user you're want to de-select all permissions and give permissions to your other role. You could probably create a rule if the user doesn't have role impact protection user deactive them. This way they won't be able to login.